# Questions that are lists of resources

Tags: discussion, questions

Following [our definition question "What are some Korean songs that are useful for learning Korean?"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/74382#74382), I've posted

[Wiki: List of songs that are useful for learning Korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/331/wiki-list-of-songs-that-are-useful-for-learning-korean/)

which is intended to become a list of Korean songs. The model it is intended to follow is something like https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/glossary-of-guitar-effects.

The idea is that

- each answer will mention one song, and the reasons why it may be a good song to study for language learners.
- ideally, each answer will be a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer
- we can try to get the question turned into a community wiki question (but I think we need a mod to do that for us)

Any comments on how best to manage this question (or this kind of question) - or whether they should be allowed - are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

As there's an answer here that is somewhat negative about the idea of individual resources questions, I'd like to suggest that actually, most **resources questions seem fine!**

Just to address a few points from the other answer,

> Are there any definitive answers in [resource questions]? They are all primarily opinion-based. How do you define good or best? What makes Naver dictionary better than Daum dictionary? That's your opinion.

There's not a clear line between "primarily opinion-based" and "good subjective", but I think many of these kinds of questions could be seen as "good subjective". They won't be opinion-based in the same way as "favourite song" - people will be able to suggest resources that have measurably helped them.

> SE doesn't encourage a question that helps only an asker and a few others (which is too localized). Is there anyone who doesn't have resources to study Korean? A question for resources is too localized.

[We now have 10 or more questions that have the resources tag](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), all with multiple upvotes and many with 100 or more views. This concern has proved somewhat unfounded, I think.

> SE doesn't encourage a question requesting for a list.

True - but we've some evidence now that list answers can work here, so that's not a reason to disallow them. There are lots of worthwhile types of questions that the SE format doesn't work perfectly for.

> Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

That's potentially the best thing about resources questions!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this issue has been one of the most controversial issues debated all across the Stack Exchange sites. There are pros and cons and they have their own reasonable and understandable arguments. My answer boils down to the following points:

**SE is not intended for a discussion forum. Questions that can generate only opinion-based answers are always closed across SE.** Its format doesn't encourage any discussion in an answer and comments. It encourages *definitive* answers and *on-topic* comments. Now, let's say a user asked "what is a good (the best) dictionary for learning a Korean?" such as [What is a good digital Korean-English dictionary?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary).

There are two answers.

(1) Use Naver. (2) Dictionary app in Mac.

Wait a minute. [Daum dictionary](http://dic.daum.net/index.do?dic=kor) is better than Naver. No, there are not many Mac users. You can just use Naver or Daum dictionaries instead of using the dictionary app in Mac.

Are there any definitive answers in the above? They are all *primarily opinion-based*. How do you define *good* or *best*? What makes Naver dictionary better than Daum dictionary? That's your opinion.

**SE doesn't encourage a question requesting for a list.** The reason is an answer could be too long and too broad depending on a question asked.

**SE doesn't encourage a general reference question.** If I can find a resource for your question, you can find it on your own. You and I both use the internet. What else? Here is the list for [Korean English dictionaries](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Korean+English+dictionary). Pick one and don't ask here.

**SE doesn't encourage a question that helps only an asker and a few others (which is too localized).** Is there anyone who doesn't have resources to study Korean? A question for resources is too localized.

I like the wordings of [Chinese SE Help Center](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that read:

> Can I ask for resources?
>
> The short answer is: **No, but it depends.**
>
> Subjective questions (lists, asking for opinions, polls), are
>   off-topic on the main SE sites, because they do not fit the Q&A format
>   in place.

We should draw a clear line between the two following questions:

> **Should not be allowed**: What is a good (the best) website/dictionary/reference/Korean song to
>   study Korean?

vs

> **Could be allowed**: I have tried this and that (prior research). But I don't think this
>   resource has this explained (specific issue and point that needs clarifying). Can you recommend other
>   resources that has this better-explained (clear comparison between the resources)?

As previously mentioned in another post, there are not many resources helping Korean learners on the internet. If we can make one or a few canonical post which will be updated whenever there is a new resource found by a user, we don't need to worry so much about a question requesting for resources. That's what other SE language sites are doing. **There is no harm in following other language sites on SE.** They have the same platform and format.

[Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) by the founder of SE

> "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and
>   you feed him for a lifetime. "**Every question and answer ultimately
>   should be about teaching and learning** -- yes, even the shopping ones.

(All emphases mine)

Comment: So is the suggestion here a single canonical post for *all* resources-based questions, with exceptions for questions pointing out problems with resources?

Comment: @topomorto I am open to suggestions for multiple canonical posts, for example one for 'dictionary', one for 'grammar', one for 'corpus', etc. But I am not sure if there will be so many resources for each of them. It's your call.

Comment: @topomorto As you know, I am a Japanese learner. I have never visited the [canonical post in Japanese SE](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) to find a resource. I have never clicked on the link. The reason is there are better resources that I can find on the internet. Because technology develops very fast. That's why the question is not good fit for SE language sites. If you are a serious language learner, you will find your own way without having to ask a question on SE.

Comment: That's definitely one of the problems with resources questions - they need some maintenance. That's part of the logic of considering making them community wiki (if we do allow them).

Comment: @topomorto Yes. But who will contribute to it on Korean SE but a few dedicated members? Whatever the format is, we can contribute one by one. I am planning to list some resources for the questions already asked. Fingers crossed. :-)

Comment: "Never doubt that a small group of thoughtful, committed citizens can change the world; indeed, it's the only thing that ever has." :)

Comment: @topomorto "Never doubt that a small group of unthoughtful and uncommitted citizens can take the ship to the mountain." It's happened and is happening.

Comment: I thought that was "Too many cooks" ? as in 사공이 많으면 배가 산으로 간다... :)

Comment: It was just a metaphor that I created. I know it doesn't make much sense in English and it is not used.